# Node.js issue with ES6 and chokidar

Tags: node.js, npm, ecmascript-6

I am having a bit of an issue using the npm module chokidar . The problem is that the value of the watcher.getWatched() returns null. Am I missing something related to ES6 and this operator?

I have an entry file.js

```
let ChokidarWatcher = require('./services/chokidarWatcher');
let FileSystemObject = require('./file-system-object');

module.exports = function (server) {
    let studentPath = 'C:/Student2';
    let fswWatcher = new ChokidarWatcher(studentPath);    
    console.log(fswWatcher.GetWatched());
};
```

I have a ChokidarWatcher class as follows

```
var chokidar = require('chokidar');
var FileSystemObject = require('../file-system-object');

class ChokidarWatcher {
constructor(studentPath) {
    this.StudentPath = studentPath;
    this.Watcher = chokidar.watch(this.StudentPath, {
        // atomic: true,
        alwaysStat: true,
        usePolling: true,
        ignoreInitial: true,
        ignored: function (path, stat) {                
            if (stat) {
                var isDir = stat.isDirectory();
                var fso = new FileSystemObject(path, stat);

                if (isDir) {
                    return (fso.name === 'node_modules' && studentPath === fso.dir) ||
                        fso.name === 'bower_components' || /[\/\\]\./.test(path)
                } else {
                    return fso.name === '.DS_Store'
                }
            }

            return false
        }
    });
}

GetMyWatcher() {
    return this.Watcher;
};

GetWatched() {

    var items = [];
    var watched = this.Watcher.getWatched();
    for (var dirpath in watched) {
        items.push(new FileSystemObject(dirpath, true))

        for (var i = 0; i < watched[dirpath].length; i++) {
            var name = watched[dirpath][i];
            var path = p.join(dirpath, name);
            if (!watched[path]) {
                // add file
                items.push(new FileSystemObject(path, false))
            }
        }
    }        
    return items
}
}

module.exports = ChokidarWatcher;
```

Comment: `getWatched` [appears to never return `null`](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar/blob/master/index.js#L682)

Comment: It returns an empty array. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

This link was helpful, I had to wait for the ready event

https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar/issues/487